# How to make PHP 5.4.40 support LDAP 5.4?

Tags: php, centos, ldap

I am deploying [LDAP](https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/)(LDAP Account Manager) 5.4 in CentOS 6.5, when I visit the main page: http://192.168.24.244/lam/templates/login.php. The browser show:

```
Your PHP has no LDAP support!Please install the LDAP extension for PHP.
```

I have tried:

```
yum install php-ldap
```

How to fix it? PHP version:5.4.40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `extension=ldap.so`in your `php.ini`